# Javascript redirect on prompt input in same window

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.open

I have been using a javascript prompt to generate reports on a website.  You click on the link, which brings up a javascript prompt.  You type in the code for the report you want and it generates that report.

So, for example, if you wanted report "ABC123", when the prompt appears, you would type ABC123 and it would open "http://example.com/reports/ABC123"

The code for this is below:

```js
function getReport(){
               var reportcode = prompt("Report Code : ", "xxx000");
               window.open("http://example.com/reports/"+reportcode,"_blank");
               return true;
            }
```

This works perfectly in terms of opening reports to print.  But I have tried to change the code to redirect to a web version of the report that opens in the same window, rather than opening a new window.

I thought that changing "_blank" to "_self" would achieve this.  But if I use "_self" or "_top" or "_parent", rather than opening the report in the same window, it simply reloads the original content of the window.

In other words, if I have the original page of "http://example.com/reports_index", rather than loading "http://exmaple.com/reports/ABC123", it simply reloads "http://example.com/reports_index".

I can't work out why it works for "_blank" but not for "_self"

Any ideas very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for opening in the same window.

```
window.location.href = "https://example.com/reports/"+reportcode
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was one of the things that I already tried.  It results in the same thing, with the original page reloading, not the new one.  I am wondering whether there is a clash with another script causing this behaviour.

Comment: The ``window,location.href`` code is the correct way to go. Like you stated, might be a collision with a framework, what frameworks are you using?